# fast loading of large hash table in Perl

Tags: performance, perl, hash

I have about 30 text files with the structure

```
wordleft1|wordright1
wordleft2|wordright2
wordleft3|wordright3
...
```

The total size of the files is about 1 GB with about 32 million lines of word combinations.

I tried a few approaches to load them as fast as possible and store the combinations within a hash

```
$hash{$wordleft} = $wordright
```

Opening file by file and reading line by line takes about 42 seconds. I then store the hash with the Storable module

```
store \%hash, $filename
```

Loading the data again

```
$hashref = retrieve $filename
```

reduces the time to about 28 seconds. I use a fast SSD drive and a fast CPU and have enough RAM to hold all the data (it takes about 7 GB).

I'm searching for a faster way to load this data into the RAM (I can't keep it there for a few reasons).

Comment: The `JSON::XS` is fast, but so is `Storable` so you'd have to compare.  Changing the design from a giantic straight hash to else would probably help directly, if possible.

Comment: Does your use allow you to read it in a separate thread while doing other useful work (or does it have to be fully loaded for anything to be done)?

Comment: It has to be fully loaded.

Comment: And it need to be this giant hash because I have to lookup for "wordleft" very often once all data has been loaded.

Comment: Try Sereal.  Also consider just keeping the data in Berkeley DB or sqlite

Comment: How often is very often?  Maybe a better way to put that: how many times will you be looking up the data for each time you read it in?  (I'd guess it would have to be in the 10s or 100s of millions to make keeping the data all in memory even possibly worth it)

Comment: Put it in a SQLite database, or *any* better format than a gig of separated values in text files.

Comment: I don't think a database is the solution. After reading the data I need to lookup "words" as fast as possible a few million times, in some special cases even a few billion (!) times. SQL selects would be too slow here. With an in-memory-hash it's fast enough.

Comment: On my notebook the simple `time perl -e '$hash{$_} = "sometext" for (1..32_000_000)'` e.g. inmemory hash assignment tooks 26 seconds...

Comment: Fun fact: I even implemented the reading and hash storing with different programming languages, in particular with C++ (using a hash class from the stdlib), Java, C# and Go. My original Perl implementation is still the fastest.

Comment: Did you try to read it with multiple threads?  It's one disk alright, but there should still be concurrency benefits.  Keep data over some, say, half-dozen files (tweak the number) and read with as many threads (maybe each into its own hash).  May get a considerable speedup, perhaps by a factor of 2 or more.

Comment: A FastMMap might also be a good idea to reload it in a fast way.

Comment: The C++ you mention ... is that of interest to you? I am puzzled by the comparison and will probably try that. But how would you use it in Perl-based code?  (Or was it just a test out of curiousity?)

Comment: It was just a test out of curiosity, because I'd like to find out how different hash map implementations behave in my special use case. I did not expect the Perl implementation to be the fastest one. (There is a C++ hash implementation from Google called "sparsehash", which has a reputation of beeing very fast. I did not try this one yet.)

Comment: Try writing it in C using SharedHashFile [1] allowing to memory map the key, value pairs into RAM. There is a small kernel overhead when you access a virtual page for the first time containing a key, value pair. Use process a to write the key, value pairs & process b for reading so there is almost no overhead due to shared memory. For extra speed keep the binary files on a RAM disk, e.g. /dev/shm. Also, use multiple processes to concurrently read and write key, value pairs; tests show over 10 million reads per second on a single box.
[1] https://github.com/simonhf/sharedhashfile

Answer (score 1):

You could try using Dan Bernstein's CDB file format using a tied hash, which will require minimal code change.  You may need to install [CDB_File](http://search.cpan.org/~toddr/CDB_File-0.98/CDB_File.pm).  On my laptop, the cdb file is opened very quickly and I can do about 200-250k lookups per second.   Here is an example script to create/use/benchmark a cdb:

**test_cdb.pl**

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;

use Benchmark qw(:all) ;
use CDB_File 'create';
use Time::HiRes qw( gettimeofday tv_interval );

scalar @ARGV or die "usage: $0 number_of_keys seconds_to_benchmark\n";
my ($size)    = $ARGV[0] || 1000;
my ($seconds) = $ARGV[1] || 10;

my $t0;
tic();

# Create CDB
my ($file, %data);

%data = map { $_ => 'something' } (1..$size);
print "Created $size element hash in memory\n";
toc();

$file = 'data.cdb';
create %data, $file, "$file.$$";
my $bytes = -s $file;
print "Created data.cdb [ $size keys and values, $bytes bytes]\n";
toc();

# Read from CDB
my $c = tie my %h, 'CDB_File', 'data.cdb' or die "tie failed: $!\n";
print "Opened data.cdb as a tied hash.\n";
toc();

timethese( -1 * $seconds, {
          'Pick Random Key'    => sub { int rand $size },
          'Fetch Random Value' => sub { $h{ int rand $size }; },
});

tic();
print "Fetching Every Value\n";
for (0..$size) {
    no warnings; # Useless use of hash element
    $h{ $_ };
}
toc();

sub tic {
    $t0 = [gettimeofday];    
}

sub toc {
    my $t1 = [gettimeofday];
    my $elapsed = tv_interval ( $t0, $t1);
    $t0 = $t1;
    print "==> took $elapsed seconds\n";
}
```

**Output ( 1 million keys, tested over 10 seconds )**

```
./test_cdb.pl 1000000 10

Created 1000000 element hash in memory
==> took 2.882813 seconds
Created data.cdb [ 1000000 keys and values, 38890944 bytes]
==> took 2.333624 seconds
Opened data.cdb as a tied hash.
==> took 0.00015 seconds
Benchmark: running Fetch Random Value, Pick Random Key for at least 10 CPU seconds...
Fetch Random Value: 10 wallclock secs (10.46 usr +  0.01 sys = 10.47 CPU) @ 236984.72/s (n=2481230)
Pick Random Key:  9 wallclock secs (10.11 usr +  0.02 sys = 10.13 CPU) @ 3117208.98/s (n=31577327)
Fetching Every Value
==> took 3.514183 seconds
```

**Output ( 10 million keys, tested over 10 seconds )**

```
./test_cdb.pl 10000000 10

Created 10000000 element hash in memory
==> took 44.72331 seconds
Created data.cdb [ 10000000 keys and values, 398890945 bytes] 
==> took 25.729652 seconds
Opened data.cdb as a tied hash.
==> took 0.000222 seconds
Benchmark: running Fetch Random Value, Pick Random Key for at least 10 CPU seconds...
Fetch Random Value: 14 wallclock secs ( 9.65 usr +  0.35 sys = 10.00 CPU) @ 209811.20/s (n=2098112)
Pick Random Key: 12 wallclock secs (10.40 usr +  0.02 sys = 10.42 CPU) @ 2865335.22/s (n=29856793)
Fetching Every Value
==> took 38.274356 seconds
```

Comment: I tried this. Creating the database is fast enough and opening the database is really fast indeed. Unfortunately, lookups took about 6 times longer than with an in-memory-hash and therefore the overall running time of my task is longer than reading all data into a hash.

But I'll keep this module in mind, because it may come in handy for other tasks. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You could try making a copy of the cdb hash `my %copy = %tied_hash;` to make the lookups faster (3x faster on my laptop), but the copy may take too long for you.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you do have a good use case for wanting an in-memory perl hash.

For faster storing/retrieving, I would recommend Sereal ([Sereal::Encoder](http://p3rl.org/Sereal::Encoder)/[Sereal::Decoder](http://p3rl.org/Sereal::Decoder)).  If your disk storage is slow, you may even want to enable Snappy compression.

Comment: I tried Sereal. I takes 25 seconds to read the data back, the Storable module tooks 28 seconds. Sereal is a little bit faster, but it takes a lot of memory while encoding, because unlike Storable it can't write into a file directly (at least I found no way to do so).