# Fastest way to populate a hash in perl

Tags: performance, perl, hash, populate

I am trying filling a hash in perl from a file of around 564k lines, and the code is taking like 1.6~2.1 seconds to execute, while the equivalent in C# takes around 0.8 seconds to finish. Is there any better way to do it in Perl ?

I have tried so far :

```
# 1 - this version take ~ +1.6 seconds to fill the hash from file with ~ 564000
my %voc;
open(F,"<$voc_file");
while(defined(my $line=<F>)) {
    chomp($line);
    $voc{$line} = 1;
}
close(F);
```

and this

```
# 2 - this version take ~ +2.1 seconds to fill the hash from file with ~ 564000
my %voc;
my @voc_keys;
my @array_of_ones;
open(F,"<$voc_file");
my $voc_keys_index = 0;
while(defined(my $line=<F>)) {
    chomp($line);
    $voc_keys[$voc_keys_index] = $line;
    $array_of_ones[$voc_keys_index] = 1;
    $voc_keys_index ++;
}
@voc{@voc_keys} = @array_of_ones;
close(F);
```

In c#, I am using :

```
var voc = new Dictionary<String, int>();
foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(pathToVoc_file))
{
    var trimmedline = line.TrimEnd(new char[] { '\n' });
    voc[trimmedline] = 1;
}
```

And it takes only 700~800 ms

Comment: What happens if you build a single array whose elements alternate between `$line` and `1`, and then write `%voc = @voc_keys_and_ones`?

Comment: I'd suggest trying to benchmark with something like `Devel::NYTprof` because it's really hard to reproduce the problem for us to analyse. I would suggest that it _might_ be the hash allocation, and you might get a bit of performance with `keys %hash = 564000;` File IO is usually one of the biggest culprits though, but that should be consistent between your two samples.

Comment: Of course C# is going to be faster. (That said, the Perl code only takes 500 ms on my ancient Windows machine. The file consists of 20-character lines plus CRLF.)

Comment: @Yahla: It seems strange to engage the whole world with saving a few tenths of a second. As **toolic** says, please explain why a difference of 0.8 sec matters to you.

Comment: Simply, this part is only a step in a pipe of actions between the user request and the response, overall I am at 5 to 6 secs. So there is nothing wrong with optimizing the process at every level. My assumption was that it should be a way to populate a big hash within a fraction of time.

Comment: There is discussion where the hash load is instant but the lookup is slow using tied hash : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43125309/fast-loading-of-large-hash-table-in-perl

Comment: @Yahia: Then rather than attempting to optimise the disk-bound section, I would take a look at the rest, and probably remove the pipes and write the whole thing in Perl.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Definitely avoiding storing 1's as the data and using exists can save time and memory.  You can eke out even more by removing the block from the loop:

```
my %voc;
open(F,"<$voc_file");
chomp, undef $voc{$_} while <F>;
close(F);
```

Benchmark results (using 20 character lines):

```
Benchmark: running ikegami, original, statementmodifier, statementmodifier_undef for at least 10 CPU seconds...
   ikegami: 10 wallclock secs ( 9.54 usr +  0.46 sys = 10.00 CPU) @  2.10/s (n=21)
  original: 10 wallclock secs ( 9.62 usr +  0.45 sys = 10.07 CPU) @  2.09/s (n=21)
statementmodifier: 10 wallclock secs ( 9.61 usr +  0.48 sys = 10.09 CPU) @  2.18/s (n=22)
statementmodifier_undef: 11 wallclock secs ( 9.85 usr +  0.48 sys = 10.33 CPU) @  2.23/s (n=23)
```

Benchmark:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Benchmark 'timethese';

my $voc_file = 'rand.txt';

sub check {
    my ($voc) = @_;
    unless (keys %$voc == 564000) {
        warn "bad number of keys ", scalar keys %$voc;
    }
    chomp(my $expected_line = `head -1 $voc_file`);
    unless (exists $voc->{$expected_line}) {
        warn "bad data";
    }
    return;
}

timethese(-10, {
    'statementmodifier' => sub {
        my %voc;
        open(F,"<$voc_file");
        chomp, $voc{$_} = 1 while <F>;
        close(F);
        #check(\%voc);
        return;
    },
    'statementmodifier_undef' => sub {
        my %voc;
        open(F,"<$voc_file");
        chomp, undef $voc{$_} while <F>;
        close(F);
        #check(\%voc);
        return;
    },
    'original' => sub {
        my %voc;
        open(F,"<$voc_file");
        while(defined(my $line=<F>)) {
            chomp($line);
            $voc{$line} = 1;
        }
        close(F);
        #check(\%voc);
        return;
    },
    'ikegami' => sub {
        my %voc;
        open(F,"<$voc_file");
        while(defined(my $line=<F>)) {
            chomp($line);
            undef $voc{$line};
        }
        close(F);
        #check(\%voc);
        return;
    },
});
```

(Original incorrect answer replaced with this.)

Comment: please don't use File::Slurp in SO answers.. it encourages people to keep using it! :)

Answer (score 1):

Of course C# is going to be faster.

You could save a little time and some memory by replacing

```
$voc{$line} = 1;  ...  if ($voc{$key}) { ... }  ...
```

with

```
undef $voc{$line};  ...  if (exists($voc{$key})) { ... }  ...
```

Comment: Seems like improvement of 100ms in average at populating the hash